# Is there a way to control where a nested Material UI select in a popper gets mounted in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to place a select menu in a Popper. The issue I'm running into is that the nested select menu wants to mount the popup that comes out of it on the body as a neighbor and not a child of popper. This causes the clickaway event to fire. Here's the code to reproduce it:

```html
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Popper from "@material-ui/core/Popper";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import ClickAwayListener from "@material-ui/core/ClickAwayListener";

export default function App() {
  const [popperAnc, setPopperAnc] = useState(null);

  const popperOpen = Boolean(popperAnc);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div
        onClick={e => {
          setPopperAnc(e.currentTarget);
        }}
      >
        Popper anchor
      </div>
      <div style={{ position: "absolute" }}>
        <Popper open={popperOpen} anchorEl={popperAnc}>
          <ClickAwayListener
            onClickAway={e => {
              setPopperAnc(null);
            }}
          >
            <TextField select label="Menu">
              <MenuItem value="select1">Select me!</MenuItem>
            </TextField>
          </ClickAwayListener>
        </Popper>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-bassi-liwdc?file=/src/App.js:0-1013

Comment: You can use the `disablePortal={true}` on the Popper, but I'm not so sure this is what you refer to. It will place the Popper under the save div (the one you positioned as absolute), but you still have issues with your MenuItem there.

Comment: Yea, the disablePortal will mount the modal from the popover in the div like you said, but the issue is that I can't use a selector in there because it ends up mounting next to the div.

Comment: what do you mean by "use a selector in there"? what kind of selector? what exactly is your issue?

Comment: The TextField opens its options in a separate popover. This is mounted somewhere outside of the Popper's popover; when I click it to select an option it fires a click event outside of the Popper's popover because of this. That causes the clickAway event to fire from the ClickAwayListener - closing the Popper which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: So your issue is not with the `Popper`, but with the `Select` (which is rendered under the `body` instead of inside the ClickAwayListener)

Comment: It's the list the Select generates, yes.

Comment: So change your `TextField` to select and try to handle what you get inside. This is where I would start.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. If you need to use `Select` - just use it (don't use `TextField`, it doesn't make any sense).
2. You need to make sure that the second popper is not rendered as a portal (you need to set `disabledPortal` on the `MenuProps` of the `Select` element.
3. You need to tell the new menu where to position itself and what will be it's size.

---

```
  <div style={{ position: "absolute" }}>
    <Popper open={popperOpen} anchorEl={popperAnc}>
      <ClickAwayListener
        onClickAway={e => {
          console.log("click away");
          setPopperAnc(null);
        }}
      >
        <div>
          <div>Wow</div>
          <Select
            label="Menu"
            MenuProps={{
              disablePortal: true,
              anchorEl: this,
              style: { marginTop: "20px", width: "150px", height: "200px" }
            }}
          >
            <MenuItem value="select1">Select me!</MenuItem>
          </Select>
        </div>
      </ClickAwayListener>
    </Popper>
  </div>
```

Here is a working example:  https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-nested-popper-4uu5l?file=/src/App.js